# rails 5 authlogic cryptic user_session error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to set up Authlogic with Rails 5 (hence the `user_session_params.to_h`), and when I try to create a new session, I get the following error message with which I don't know what to do. Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

**puts @user_session.errors.inspect**

`#<Authlogic::Session::Validation::Errors:0x0000000cb9b7a0 @base=#<UserSession: {:email=>"test@test.com", :password=>"<protected>"}>, @messages={:base=>["You did not provide any details for authentication."]}, @details={:base=>[{:error=>"You did not provide any details for authentication."}]}>`

Here's the code:

**UserSessionsController**

```
class UserSessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user_session = UserSession.new
  end

  def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(user_session_params.to_h)
    puts @user_session.errors.inspect

    if @user_session.save
      flash[:notice] = "Login successful, thank you!"
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Something went wrong, sorry."
    end
  end

  def destroy
    current_user_session.destroy
    redirect_to new_user_sessions_path
  end

  private

  def user_session_params
    params.require(:user_session).permit(:email, :password, :remember_me)
  end
end
```

**UserSession**

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
end
```

**View**

```
<%= form_for @user_session, url: user_sessions_path, method: :post, html: {class: 'form-horizontal', role: 'form'} do |f| %>
    <div class='form-group'>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Login' %>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Password' %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit 'Login', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

**User**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    acts_as_authentic do |c|
        c.login_field = 'email'
    end
end
```

Comment: You need to call `@user_session.valid?` before your `puts` so that `errors` actually print something if the validation fails. Please update the question.

Comment: Added that. Now it seems that it doesn't recognize the authentication details while actually using the correct authentication details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be an **issue of Authlogic under Rails 5**.

You've probably already seen [this comment](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/issues/487#issuecomment-198212009) from github issue 487 but you probably followed only the first step. The step nr. 2 deals with broken Authlogic callbacks under Rails 5 and there is a link to [pull request #488](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/pull/488) where a fix is developed. Currently, your only options seem to be the following:

- You can try [this branch of Authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/pull/488) that allegedly has the callbacks issue fixed, as [commented](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/pull/488#issuecomment-216301593) in the pull request 488.
- You can of course wait until things settle down and Authlogic gets an official support for Rails5.

Comment: Yup, for the time being I decided to write my own simple authentication around `has_secure_password` and I'll change it later.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this issue was fixed starting with Authlogic version 3.5.0. Currently 3.5.0 still hasn't been released as a stable version, but specifying 3.5 in your Gemfile should fix things up (it did for me, anyway):

`gem 'authlogic', '~> 3.5'`